# How can I suppress /etc/issue without losing error messages?

Tags: command-line, ssh, unix

Is it possible to tell the ssh client to not print the connects of `/etc/issue` to stdout when connecting to a remote host, but to print out any other diagnostic (e.g. error) messages?

Either using `ssh -q` or having `LogLevel quiet` in `~/.ssh/config` suppresses the `/etc/issue` printing, but also turn off error messages. I've tried `touch`ing `~/.hushlogin` as well - that stops `/etc/motd` being printed, but doesn't affect `/etc/issue`.

The most obvious solution is just to remove `/etc/issue`, but company policy dictates the file be there with dire warnings about unauthorised access. This is non-negotiable. Unfortunately, I've got a bunch of scripts that run across quite a few hosts via ssh, and the log files are a) very large and b) full of legalese. Since quite a lot of stuff runs unattended, I don't want to lose any error messages that are printed.

Comment: Thoses legalses must be static. I suggest an automated removal from log using awk or sed. I ll come with a solution tomorrow.

Answer (score 8):

**Yes**   Add a file `~/.ssh/config` containing:

```
LogLevel ERROR
```

OpenSSH displays the content of `/etc/issue` from the remote server. That parameter disables this display. Very useful when the company remote Git repo as an annoying security warning.

The [`ssh config` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html) says:

> #### `LogLevel`
>
> Gives the verbosity level that is used when logging messages
>   from ssh(1).  The possible values are: `QUIET`, `FATAL`, `ERROR`,
>   `INFO`, `VERBOSE`, `DEBUG`, `DEBUG1`, `DEBUG2`, and `DEBUG3`.
>   The default is `INFO`.  `DEBUG` and `DEBUG1` are equivalent.
>   `DEBUG2` and `DEBUG3` each specify higher levels of verbose output.

---

**Extra trick**   Add also in your `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host *
#    StrictHostKeyChecking no
     StrictHostKeyChecking accept-new
```

This prevents another annoying message. When connecting to a new host, the following security question blocks the ongoing connection. The above trick always assumes `yes`. Nevertheless in practice you always answer `yes`, isn't it?

```
The authenticity of host 'newhostname (11.222.33.44)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88:99:00.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out by [Chris Adams](https://superuser.com/users/62496/chris-adams) using `StrictHostKeyChecking no` may allow a [Man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), better use `StrictHostKeyChecking accept-new` as explained in https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#StrictHostKeyChecking.

Comment: It's very dangerous to run with `StrictHostKeyChecking no` as that allows an attacker to MITM your connection. If you want to accept new keys automatically, use `accept-new` as per: https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#StrictHostKeyChecking

Comment: Thank you @ChrisAdams for your feedback.    Have fun 

Answer (score 3):

Neither my OS X localhost or my Ubuntu server print `/etc/issue` when I ssh in (neither with a shell nor with executing a remote command), so I cannot reproduce your problem. I will try this from memory.

If you do not mind making two connections, you could do this:

```
num_lines="$(ssh yourhost 'cat /etc/issue' | wc -l)";
ssh yourhost 'your real command here' | tail +$(($num_lines / 2 + 1));
```

The first ssh command will cause `/etc/issue` to be printed twice (once by the system, once by `cat`), so the number of lines will be twice that of `/etc/issue`. The second command's output will only show the output from that number of lines plus one.

Answer (score 3):

If your log will have a bunch of sessions appended in one file, you could have your script do something like `echo START LOGGING` before running any other commands, and then `echo END LOGGING` before disconnecting, and then use a simple shell script (using sed or awk) strip out all contents of the file between END and START (ie. the boilerplate before each login).

EDIT:

Now I see that you are not logging, but instead looking for messages in the window - I recommend creating logs and scanning the logs instead of relying on terminal window output alone - this is much more flexible, and allows referring back to errors from previous sessions if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can set this from the commandline with:

`ssh -o loglevel=ERROR`

If you are using rsync (as was the case for me when Googling this problem), you can do it by specifying the ssh connection commandline to rsync as:

`rsync -e 'ssh -o loglevel=ERROR'`

Comment: Thank goodness I don't need to file a ticket with my sysadmin guys to change `/etc/issue` which would have taken weeks.

Comment: Yay! Glad to help.

Answer (score -1):

No.

When the host sends back lines of text, how can the SSH client know which lines came from the host's /etc/issue, and which ones are more interesting messages?  It can't.

Comment: it can know because /etc/issue is printed before you run any commands, it won't show up in the middle of a session, ever